# Python-Modulus-Stuck with a coin-for-given-dollar-amount scenario

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, modulus

**Specs:** Ubuntu 13.04, Python 3.3.1

**General Background:** total beginner to Python;

**Question-specific background:** I'm exhausted trying to solve this problem, and I'm aware that, besides its instructional value for learning Python, this problem is boring and does not in any way make this world a better place :-( So I'd be even more grateful if you could share some guidance on this exhausting problem. But really don't want to waste your time if you are not interested in this kind of problems.

**What I intended to do:**  "Calculate the number of basic American coins given a value less than 1 dollar. A penny is worth 1 cent, a nickel is worth 5 cents, a dime is worth 10 cents,
and a quarter is worth 25 cents. It takes 100 cents to make 1 dollar. So given an amount less than 1 dollar (if using floats, convert to integers for this exercise), calculate the number of each type of coin necessary to achieve the amount, maximizing the number of larger denomination coins. For example, given $0.76, or 76 cents, the correct output would be "3 quarters and 1 penny." Output such as "76 pennies" and "2 quarters, 2 dimes, 1 nickel, and 1 penny" are not acceptable."

**What I was able to come up with:**

```
penny = 1
nickel = 5
dime = 10
quarter = 25

i = input("Please enter an amount no more than 1 dollar(in cents): ")
i = int(i)

if i > 100:
    print ("Please enter an amount equal or less than 100. ")
elif i >= quarter:
    quarter_n = i % quarter
    i = i - quarter * quarter_n
    if i >= dime:
        dime_n = i % dime
        i = i - dime * dime_n
        if i >= nickel:
            nickel_n = i % nickel
            i = i - nickel * nickel_n
            if i >= penny:
                penny_n = i % penny
                print (quarter_n,"quarters,",dime_n,"dimes",nickel_n,"nickels",penny_n,"pennies")
        else:
            if i >= penny:
                penny_n = i % penny
                print (quarter_n,"quarters,",dime_n,"dimes",penny_n,"pennies")
    else:
        if i >= nickel:
            nickel_n = i % nickel
            i = i - nickel * nickel_n
            if i >= penny:
                penny_n = i % penny
                print (quarter_n,"quarters,",nickel_n,"nickels",penny_n,"pennies")
        else:
            if i >= penny:
                penny_n = i % penny
                print (quarter_n,"quarters,",penny_n,"pennies")
else:
    if i >= dime:
        dime_n = i % dime
        i = i - dime * dime_n
        if i >= nickel:
            nickel_n = i % nickel
            i = i - nickel * nickel_n
            if i >= penny:
                penny_n = i % penny
                print (dime_n,"dimes",nickel_n,"nickels",penny_n,"pennies")
        else:
            if i >= penny:
                penny_n = i % penny
                print (dime_n,"dimes",penny_n,"pennies")
    else:
        if i >= nickel:
            nickel_n = i % nickel
            i = i - nickel * nickel_n
            if i >= penny:
                penny_n = i % penny
                print (nickel_n,"nickels",penny_n,"pennies")
        else:
            if i >= penny:
                penny_n = i % penny
                print (penny_n,"pennies")
```

This solution, though the best I could come up with, does not work as expected when fed with actual input numbers. And I'm unable to figure out why. Besides, I know that even from sheer size of the code that something is wrong. I searched for similar questions but the closest I got was one that dealt with very difficult math which I couldn't understand.

**My question:** I know I can't ask for a complete solution because that's down to me to figure it out. I'll appreciate either a) general pointer on the correct line of thinking b) critiques to my current code/line of thinking so that I might be able to improve it.

Thank you for taking the time, even just reading this!

Comment: You might want to move that to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your solution may actually be working if you do a "find and replace" for all the mod operators `%`, switching in integer division `//`.

Say you have `76` cents and want to find the number of quarters. Using `76 % 25` results in `1` whereas `76 // 25` is `3`.

With regard to the code, you should probably be thinking in terms of iterating over the possible coin values rather than a huge `if`, `elif` mess.

Try something like this. The only part that may need some explaining is using `divmod` but its really just a `tuple` of the integer division, modulo result. You can use that to get the number of coins and the new amount, respectively.

```
def coins_given(amount):
    coins = [(25, 'quarter'), (10, 'dime'), (5, 'nickel'), (1, 'penny')]
    answer = {}
    for coin_value, coin_name in coins:
        if amount >= coin_value:
            number_coin, amount = divmod(amount, coin_value)
            answer[coin_name] = number_coin
    return answer

print coins_given(76)
# {'quarter': 3, 'penny': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I learned from your answer that I actually misunderstood about what `%` means. `//` produced what I actually wanted. And thanks for suggesting the alternative solution too! Though I'm still a little confused about the `number_coin, amount = divmod(amount, coin_value)` part. Does `divmod(amount, coin_value)` equal to what `amount // coin_value` produces? or is it  just put result of a integer division and its remainder as a pair of tuple onto the left?

Comment: `divmod(76, 25) == (76//25, 76%25) == (3, 1)` Its really just a shortcut.

Comment: what would I add to this code if I want for example, if the input is 138 then the output should be [5; 1; 0; 3] to denote that 5
quarters, 1 dime, 0 nickels and 3 pennies.

Answer (score 2):

i think your algorithm is too complicated,
you don't need all the elifs and the elses
just check with and if and then modidy the remaining amount until you get to zero

something like this

```
penny = 1
nickel = 5
dime = 10
quarter = 25
q = 0
d = 0
n = 0
p = 0
i = input("Please enter an amount no more than 1 dollar(in cents): ")
i = int(i)


if i>=25:
    q = i/quarter
    i %= quarter
if i>=10:
    d = i/dime
    i%=dime
if i>=5:
    n = i/nickel
    i %= nickel
if i>0:
    p = i/penny
    i = 0

print "The coins are %i quarters, %i dimes, %i nickels and %i pennys." %(q , d, n, p)

>>> 
Please enter an amount no more than 1 dollar(in cents): 99
The coins are 3 quarters, 2 dimes, 0 nickels and 4 pennys.
>>> 
Please enter an amount no more than 1 dollar(in cents): 76
The coins are 3 quarters, 0 dimes, 0 nickels and 1 pennys.
```

Comment: Thank you! An elegant solution! Though I'm not yet familiar with string formatting. I'll for sure save this for study later :-)

Comment: Nothing mate,@jared 's was an elegant,more pythonic solution.Mine was more,a simpler approach of your algorithm.String formatting really helps a lot,i am sure u will appreciate it when you got familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
dime=10
nickel=5
penny=1
quarter=25

def change(cents):
    changeIs = ""
    qs = cents/quarter
    cents %= quarter
    if qs > 0 :
        changeIs += str(qs) + " quarter(s)"
    ds = cents/dime
    cents %= dime
    if ds > 0 :
        changeIs += " " + str(ds) + " dime(s)"
    ns = cents/nickel
    cents %= nickel
    if ns > 0 :
        changeIs +=  " " + str(ns) + " nickel(s)"
    if cents > 0 :
        changeIs +=  " " + str(cents) + " cent(s)"
    return changeIs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cents=int(raw_input("Enter the change: "))
    print change(cents)
```